# What is the support timeline for Graph apis

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I see that there are 3 graph api versions - unversioned, v1.0, v2.0. Do these apis expire at any time and what support is available for previous versions.

For example, searching public posts are not available in 2.0 unless a company becomes Partner of Facebook but available in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

unversioned will get 2.0 (or the newest version, like 2.1 after it is released.)

v1.0 can be used only by apps created before 4/30/2014, and will stop working on 4/30/2015.

v2.0 will be supported for at least 2 years.